# Broken expect/TCL script

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have a Bash script which includes an expect/TCL EOF script in a separate function. The expect script exits with 0-4 possible exit codes depending on what the expect/TCL script determines from the remote device, and within an `if ... elif ... else` statement I write a specific string to a variable depending on this exit code (within that expect/TCL function). Control is then passed back to the Bash script where a `case` block runs on the string contained within said variable contains.

The trouble I am experiencing is that my Bash function which contains the expect/TCL script does not catch exit code 3 (well actually it does as I can see the log file entry correctly writes to the log file, but if I echo the value of the exit code it actually catches a zero when the situation should be a 3) and thus my `case` statement is not switching accurately.

Can you find the bug?

(I've chopped the script right down to just these parts for purpose of keeping the post concise and specific so just assume that the surrounding code is running OK).

```
function myTclFunc()
{
    /usr/bin/expect<<EOF
    proc log_msg {msg {to_stdout no}} {
        set log_line "[timestamp -format {[%d/%m/%Y @ %T]}] \$msg"
        set fh [open ~/mylogfile.log a]
        puts \$fh \$log_line
        close \$fh
        if {\$to_stdout} {puts \$log_line}
    }

    ;#exp_internal 1
    set timeout 5
    set send_human {.1 .3 1 .05 2}

    spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "[USER]@$1"

    expect {
        "password: " { send -h "[MY_PASSWD]\r" }
        timeout { log_msg "A RELEVANT STRING TO LOG $1 / $2"; exit 1 }
    }

    set timeout 3
    sleep 1 ;
    send -h "[COMMAND A]\r" ;
    expect {
        timeout { exit 1 }
        -re {\m\d{1,}(\.\d{1,}){3}\M}
    }
    if { ! [regexp {192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.{2}[0-9]{1,3}} $expect_out(0,string)]} {
        send -h "[COMMAND B]\r" ;
    }
    expect {
        "[STRING 1]" { 
            send -h "[COMMAND C]\r" ;
            log_msg "Problem F on $1 / $2" ;
            exit 3
        }
        "[STRING 2]" { 
            send -h "[COMMAND D]\r" ;
            sleep 1 ;
            send -h "[COMMAND E]\r" ;
            send -h "\r" ;
            puts "\r"
            ;#exit 0
        }
    }
    expect eof
EOF
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        passBack="GOOD";
    elif [[ $? -eq 3 ]]; then
        passBack="BAD";
    else
        passBack="TIMEOUT";
    fi;
}

[...snipped code...]
myTclFunc $myVar $1

case "$passBack" in
GOOD)
    echo ""
    exit 0
    ;;
BAD)
    echo ""
    exit 4
    ;;
CHECK)
    echo ""
    exit 3
    ;;
esac;
[...snipped code...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixture of Shell and Tcl can be a bit tricky at times. In particular, you are wanting to deliver `\` into the regular expression engine in a few places, inside a here-document with an unquoted delimiter word. Fortunately, you're otherwise putting the REs inside braces, so it's *just confusing* and not *super-confusing!*

The relevant part of the bash documentation says:

> ## Here Documents
>
> This  type  of  redirection  instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing  only  *word*  (with  no  trailing blanks)  is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>    <<[-]word
>        here-document
>    delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,  or pathname expansion is performed on *word*.  If any characters in *word* are quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on word,  and  the lines  in the here-document are not expanded.  If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter  expansion,  command  substitution,  and arithmetic expansion.  In the latter case, the character sequence **\<newline>** is ignored, and **\** must be used  to  quote the characters **\**, **$**, and **`**.
>
> If the redirection operator is **<<-**, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and  the  line  containing  *delimiter*.   This allows  here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Because you're using the unquoted version, you want to double up the backslashes that you want the Tcl interpreter to see. In your case, that's just the ones in the regular expressions. Thus, you want this (with everything above and below unchanged, I think):

```
    expect {
        timeout { exit 1 }
        -re {\\m\\d{1,}(\\.\\d{1,}){3}\\M}
    }
    if { ! [regexp {192\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.{2}[0-9]{1,3}} $expect_out(0,string)]} {
        send -h "[COMMAND B]\\r" ;
    }
```

Oh, and you also need `\\r` (as above) throughout your script instead of `\r`.

---

I think it would be easier to split your script into two files, one which is just Bash code and the other which is just Tcl code, at least while you're developing it. Then you'd be able to make things work without having to fuss around with many layers of quoting. (The things you're substituting in now could instead be passed over as arguments to the script.)

When packaging everything back together, bash's `printf %q` may be helpful. It'll generate something hard to read, but it is a *packaging* operation after all…

---

And in relation to the error codes? The problem there is simpler; the test itself — `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]` — sets the error code. You have to save it to a proper variable and then test against that.

Here, check these boiled down cases:

```
bash-3.2$ ( exit 2 ); if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo ok; elif [[ $? -eq 2 ]]; then echo good; else echo bad; fi
bad
bash-3.2$ ( exit 2 ); echo $?; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo ok; elif [[ $? -eq 2 ]]; then echo good; else echo bad; fi
2
ok
bash-3.2$ ( exit 2 ); code=$?; echo $code; if [[ $code -eq 0 ]]; then echo ok; elif [[ $code -eq 2 ]]; then echo good; else echo bad; fi
2
good
```

The first one is approximately what you're doing right now, the second shows just how non-obvious it can get — the intervening `echo` changes the result — and the third shows how to deal with it (storing the value in `code` here, but the name isn't really all that special).

Comment: Useful, though unfortunately I'm still seeing the problem whereby exit code 3 is not caught.

Comment: @uncle-junky Hah; classic bash problem there. You still need to fis the other issues too…

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm surprised my Oreilly book 'Shell Scripting' does not include this... Thanks, I will test.

Comment: I would make sure that condition '3' and probably '2' exit from the ssh session so you are getting the return code from your script as opposed to the ssh session.  So in other words, make sure your expect script ( if logged in ) does a "send "exit\n\r" to the remote machine"

Comment: Well spotted, I have handled that though.